# How to send cron output only if an output exists

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have the simplest bash script MEM.SH to monitor RAM state

```
#!/bin/bash
free=$(free -mt | grep Total | awk '{print $4}')
if [ $free -lt 256 ]; then
date
echo Warning, free memory is ${free} mb only. 
date
fi
```

So if free RAM is less then 256 mb - it gives on shell the following output

```
[root@server ~]# sh /tools/mem.sh
Fri Dec 19 11:19:44 CET 2014
Warning, free memory is 245 mb only.
Fri Dec 19 11:19:45 CET 2014
```

Accordingly, if free RAM is more than 256 mb - it shows no any output.

I set up cron to run every minute

```
sh /tools/mem.sh | mail -s "Server Low Memory" email@me.com
```

The problem is - I have every minute email with empty output, although I need only emails where output exists as above described - wnen free memory actually less than 256 mb

I already tried

```
sh /tools/mem.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null | mail -s "Server Low Memory" email@me.com
sh /tools/mem.sh > /dev/null | mail -s "Server Low Memory" email@me.com
```

but no effect, still same emailing both empty and actual outputs.

Variant 2 - I even tried

```
sh /tools/mem.sh >/dev/null 2>/tools/mem.txt ; if [ -s /tools/mem.txt ] ; then mail -s "Server Low Memory" < /tools/mem.txt email@me.com ; fi
```

But it does not write anything to /tools/mem.txt - even if output exists - /tools/mem.txt has 0 (zero) value.

As a result - it does not send ANY email (even if necessary)

What is the problem with output above if it does not write anything to /tools/mem.txt ?

May be here is another variant of a solution ?

May be bash script itself should generate output in an another way ?

Thanks in advance for the hints and variants to try !

Comment: Manually script is working?

Comment: Put `| mail -s "Server Low Memory" email@me.com` part inside mem.sh?

Comment: @anishsane ? how ? can't catch your idea. May be an example ?

Comment: Alternately, as you already found out in variant 2, `sh /tools/mem.sh >/tools/mem.txt; if [ -s /tools/mem.txt ] ; then mail -s "Server Low Memory" < /tools/mem.txt email@me.com ; fi`. This should work. Your variant 2 code has o/p redirected to `/dev/null`. Thus it is always empty.

Comment: @MiyaG - of course, you can see shell output I copied in my question body

Comment: "how?": Instead of `echo free memory is ...` write `mail -s` statement on the .sh file.

Comment: @Serge One more question, have you access to your server as root level?

Comment: @anishsane - THANKS your first solution works perfect - I mean you're right just to cut /dev/null from my Variant 2. The matter is solved !

Comment: @MiyaG how else I could have shell output :) thank you for attention but the matter is solved as you can see above

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this problem occurs due to script/logs file permission and ownership of script/logs files. The same problem was faced by me. I found that my scrip owner was not a super user e.g. root.

So, you have to set the permission and ownership of your scrip as super user. Find below.

First of all edit your `crontab` as super user.

```
[abc@host] crontab -e
```

and save crontab :wq!

Now set permission for script

```
[abc@host] chmod +x script.sh
[abc@host] chown root:root script.sh
```

Now restart your crontab.

```
[abc@host] /etc/init.d/crond restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `| mail -s "Server Low Memory" email@me.com` part inside mem.sh? –  anishsane

Alternately, as you already found out in variant 2,

```
sh /tools/mem.sh >/tools/mem.txt; if [ -s /tools/mem.txt ] ; then mail -s "Server Low Memory" < /tools/mem.txt email@me.com ; fi
```

. This should work. Your variant 2 code has o/p redirected to `/dev/null`. Thus it is always empty. –  anishsane